# dynamically update combobox 2 with selection of combobox1 wxpython

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, wxpython

I am new to python and trying to learn some basic code. I was working on some project and I have the demo code below.

The only thing which I cannot change in this code is the **__init__** and **def update()** part coz they are linked to some other code as well.

The problem is when I select value as '2' on combobox-1, I get values as 'B100,B200,B300' in combobox-2 but if I select value '1' on combobox-1 after selecting value '2', I don't get any updated list on my combobox-2. Copy and paste on IDE the code if needed.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#20_combobox.py

import wx
import wx.lib.inspection

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.p1 = wx.Panel(self)
        lst = ['1','2','3']
        self.st = wx.ComboBox(self.p1, -1, choices = self.lst1(), style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        self.st2 = wx.ComboBox(self.p1, -1, choices = self.lst2(), style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)

        self.st.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.update)
        self.st2.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.update)


    def lst1(self):
        lst=['1','2','3']
        return lst

    def lst2(self):
        lst =['A100','A200','A300','B100','B200','B300','C100','C200','C300','D100','D200','D300']
        dummyvar=[]
        dummyvar1=[]

        if self.st.GetStringSelection() == '1':
            self.st2.Clear()
            for number in lst:
                if number.startswith('A'):
                # if number.startswith('A'):
                    self.st2.Append(number)
                    self.st.Hide()

        elif self.st.GetStringSelection() == '2':
            self.st2.Clear()
            for number in lst:
                if number.startswith('B'):
                    self.st2.Append(number)



        return lst


    def update(self, event):
        self.lst1a=self.lst1()
        self.lst2a=self.lst2()


class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, '20_combobox.py')
        frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
#    wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Python is a very good language for learners because it is very specific and (almost) always very helpful when it tells you what it did not like. So, in your case, what did python thell you it did not like when you selected '2' first, then '1' (actually the order does not matter, e. g. selecting '2' twice give exact the same error)?

Comment: So can anyone tell me how am I suppose to make the the combobox-2 dependent on combobox-1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not confuse object attributes and methods. `self.list1 != self.list1()`, a fact Python was trying to tell you by raising an error when calling `self.update` the second time. See an example with clearer separation of concerns:

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.p1 = wx.Panel(self)
        self.lst1 = ['1','2','3']
        self.lst2 = self.get_lst2()

        self.st = wx.ComboBox(self.p1, -1, choices = self.lst1, style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        self.st2 = wx.ComboBox(self.p1, -1, choices = self.lst2, style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER, pos=(-1,100), size=(100,-1))

        self.st.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.update)

    def get_lst2(self, selectn=None):
        lst =['A100','A200','A300','B100','B200','B300','C100','C200','C300','D100','D200','D300']

        ret =  []
        if selectn == '1':
            for entry in lst:
                if entry.startswith('A'):
                    ret.append(entry)
        elif selectn == '2':
            for entry in lst:
                if entry.startswith('B'):
                    ret.append(entry)
        else:
            ret = lst
        return ret

    def update(self, event):
        selectn = self.st.GetStringSelection()
        self.lst2 = self.get_lst2(selectn)
        self.st2.Clear()
        for number in self.lst2:
            self.st2.Append(number)
        if selectn == '1':
            self.st.Hide()
```